# Removing an element without an arraylist or methods

Tags: java, arraylist, element

I'm trying to have a user enter in the number of the element they want to delete and then delete that element and have the numbers shift to the left. I can't use an arrayList and I haven't learned methods. Can anyone please help me? My code is below

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class questionFive
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int [] numbers = new int [5];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int delete;

    for (int i= 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.print("Enter in your values for the array: ");
      numbers[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    for(int val : numbers)
    {
      System.out.println("The next value is " +
                         val);
    } 

    System.out.println("What element would you like to delete?");
    delete = keyboard.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
     numbers[i] = delete;
      System.out.println(i);
    }

    while (delete <=5){
     System.out.println("Invalid element. Try again.");
     delete = keyboard.nextInt();
   //  numbers[delete];
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Won't be giving you any code, as this is an exercise you should solve yourself, but seems pretty straightforward: If you are *deleting* something, you don't care about it anymore, right? So there is no problem in ***overriding it***. In that case, just pick the stuff that's ***after it*** in the array, and move it one step back. TIP: You even have the loop for that ready; you just need a `bool` flag to signal the `deleted` element has been found and deleted in a *previous iteration* of the loop already, and the `current` element can be moved one *index* lower (left). 

Comment: @AlmightyR in Java we say `boolean`, not `bool`

Comment: @KevinAnderson I know; I have a few years of experience with Java; but it's pretty obvious that I'm talking about a `boolean`, so why not shorten it to `bool`? My `code formats` aren't always used for `code`, you see? I use them to `highlight` stuff sometimes... So don't you dare get all technical with me, boy! 

Comment: Well, @AlmightyR, OP has **zero** years' experience with Java.  The less confusion for him or her, the better...

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: @KevinAnderson Argh! A point I can't argue against! Shoo! Go away!  --- Seriously though, `bool` VS `boolean` is not going to cause any major confusion, and it can just as easily be argued that, that even tough it's not *technically* correct, `bool` is used synonymously for `boolean` so often in the programming world (as I've just demonstrated ) ,  that the OP should just #GetUsedToIt ASAP.  --- Ri~ght~?  (and get used to some wacky humor too, while he/she is at it!)

Comment: @Malia it's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Are you asking the user to enter the **value** they wish to delete or are you asking them to enter the **position** of the value they wish to delete?

Comment: @D.B. Right now he's replacing every value with the number that's input for delete ... I'd guess there is an `if` statement both missing and misused (`=` instead of `==`) there, as well as what I explained in my first comment as the missing behavior after that... But it's just what I can *assume* from looking at the code; can be totally wrong.